# Copy File ignoring Column(s)

Tags: bash, shell, copy

I have a .txt like this:

```
dummy1, dummy2, dummy3, dummy4, 
dummy1, dummy2, dummy3, dummy4,
dummy1, dummy2, dummy3, dummy4,
dummy1, dummy2, dummy3, dummy4,
dummy1, dummy2, dummy3, dummy4,
```

I want to save this information in another file, but ignoring (for example) the column 2 and/or 4. How can do it?

Comment: How can do it?  check awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the awk command then:

```
awk '{ $2=""; $4=""; print}' test.txt > new.txt
```

Where $2 is the second column and $4 is the fourth. The contents of the new.txt file will be:

```
dummy1, dummy3,
dummy1, dummy3,
dummy1, dummy3,
dummy1, dummy3,
dummy1, dummy3,
```

Just change the columns in the print for different configurations. i.e.

```
awk '{ $2=""; print}' test.txt > new.txt
```

The contents of the new.txt file will be:

```
dummy1, dummy3, dummy4,
dummy1, dummy3, dummy4,
dummy1, dummy3, dummy4,
dummy1, dummy3, dummy4,
dummy1, dummy3, dummy4,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

cat test.txt
cut -d, -f 2,3,4 test.txt
cut -d, -f 1,3,4 test.txt
cut -d, -f 1 test.txt
```

Admitting all the files in the same directory